# Most efficient log "echo date"?

Tags: logging, sh, echo

My coworkers write scripts with lines like this:

```
echo "nightly $MACHINE restart begins at" `date`
```

Which outputs something like this:

```
nightly whitestar restart begins at Mon Oct 13 22:05:01 EDT 2014
```

However, trying to parse this for trimming or error detection is difficult! Also, it seems that

```
`date`
```

Is not the most efficient way to output the date, based on online discussions about subshells (and my general disdain for backticks).

Are there better ways of providing the pertinent information so it's more terse, efficient, and parsable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pure `/bin/sh`, spawning `date` is the primary way. But it isn't so bad – both Linux and BSDs are quite fast at creating new processes, and the `date` binary will be cached in memory for a while. If you don't like the look of backticks, `$(this syntax)` is generally preferred over them.

You can change the date format using `date +fmt`, giving it a strftime()-style format:

```
echo "nightly $MACHINE restart at $(date +"%F %T %z")"
echo "$(date +"%F %T %z"): $MACHINE: nightly restart"
```

...In fact, you can extend the date-format option to make `date` print the whole line – as long as you avoid or escape `%` characters in variables:

```
date +"%F %T %z: $MACHINE: nightly restart"
```

In the Bash shell, you can replace `echo` with `printf`, and use the special `%(fmt)T` format specifier, which again accepts a strftime()-style format:

```
printf "%(%F %T %z)T: %s: nightly restart\n" "$MACHINE"
```

In all examples above, `%F %T %z` (or the full version `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z`) is the "modified [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)" date format. (The regular ISO 8601 would be `%FT%T%z` or `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z`, slightly less readable.) Either of these is generally the best choice when formatting dates for future parsing.

Finally, you could forget `echo` entirely, and write directly to the system log. Most operating systems come with the `logger` function for sending to *syslog*:

```
logger -s -p user.notice "nightly restart"
```

The syslog will automatically store the date & time as well as the hostname.

Comment: Thanks! You have given some excellent food for thought. Unfortunately bash is not an option in about half of what I do (AIX/ksh), so the best parts I'll have to skip over.

Answer (score 1):

What many people don't realize, is that `date(1)` itself can be used instead of echo — with the message being part of the format. For example:

```
date '+%D %T nightly restart'
```

this is lighter and more straightforward, than the usual capturing of date's output with backticks. Unless redirected to a log-file, log-messages should, probably, be sent to `stderr` rather than `stdout`:

```
date '+%D %T nightly restart' 1>&2
```

This is my favorite method. The only better alternative is — as pointed out by grawity above — using bash's built-in implementation of `printf(1)`. Its downside is, of course, that your script becomes a bash-only one...

If you need the record to go to syslogd as well, you should be using `logger(1)` (with the `-s`) — as grawity suggests — just remember, that the flag is not available on all systems. For example, it is — rather annoyingly — missing on Solaris, including Solaris-10. (Not coincidentally, the `LOG_PERROR` define (that some implementations of `syslog(3)` recognize), is also missing on "Slowlaris"...)

Comment: Now if only you hadn't chosen the _worst date format in existence_. Five months later, deciphering "10/12/14" can be a _major_ pain to someone who hasn't lived in USA for many years... _(tip: on SU sites, en dash can be written as `&ndash;` looking nicer than `--`)_

Comment: @grawity FWIW, one would have even more fun with dates like 07/08/09. So whenever possible it is advised to use ISO 8601 format dates with 4-digit year to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

## lecho 0.3

For logging in the past, we have used the following:

```
server=$( uname -n )
lecho() {
   now=$( date '+%Y-%m-%d %T' )
   printf "[%19s]%s@%s\n: %s\n" "$now" "$USER" "$server" "$@"
}

# ...

lecho "BEGIN nightly restart"
```

*Edit:* When you're doing lots of these, printf is faster than echo. Plus the formatting of the output is very helpful when grepping for it later.